# android studio 3.1.2 выдает ошибку

Tags: android

При запуске проекта андроид студио выдает ошибку 
error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/fontFamily' with config ''

Comment: Полный текст ошибки предоставьте.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь поиском по проекту и поищите в кастомных вьюхах  кастомные атрибуты `fontFamily` - у меня такое было и их пришлось переименовывать.

Answer (score 1):

Было:

```
<attr name="fontFamily">
    <enum name="roboto" value="0"/>
    <enum name="roboto_condensed" value="1"/>
    <enum name="roboto_slab" value="2"/>
</attr>
```

Исправил на:

```
<attr name="robotofontFamily">
    <enum name="roboto" value="0"/>
    <enum name="roboto_condensed" value="1"/>
    <enum name="roboto_slab" value="2"/>
</attr>
```